# перенос строки по слогам в java

Tags: java, алгоритм, перенос

Каким алгоритмом или библиотекой можно воспользоваться для переноса строки по слогам при этом используя JFrame?
То есть чтобы из такого текста -

Конечная свинья совокупность
точно заданных
правил решения некоторого
класса задач
или набор инструкций

Конечная свинья **совокуп-

ность** точно **задан-

ных** правил решения **не-

которого** класса задач
или набор **инструк-

ций**

Comment: определение слога - достаточно нетривиальная задача. если для вас это каким-то образом отождествляется с JFrame, то ответ только один: вам очень рано решать такие задачи. займитесь основами, это будет гораздо полезнее

Comment: `вам очень рано решать такие задачи` - не согласен с предыдущим комментатором. однако он прав в том, что для решения подобной задачи нужно воспользоваться готовой библиотекой

Comment: @АлексейКовальчук Так какой библиотекой?

Comment: Если бы знал - сказал. Пробуйте разные, которые найдете в Гугле.

Comment: [Переносы на gramota.ru](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/141-perenos). Там достаточно чёткие правила, можно попробовать реализовать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy мне правила переноса не нужны были, я искал уже готовую библиотеку или алгоритм, что я прекрасно и нашёл, но за помощь спасибо.